# Was Gerald Ford's experience of losing a close election after being given a chance to correct a speech and failing to do so, unusual?

Tags: campaigning

In a 1976 debate with Governor Jimmy Carter, (sitting) President Gerald Ford (in)famously said, "Eastern Europe is not under Soviet domination."

http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1844704_1844706_1844449,00.html

The questioner, Max Frankel gave Ford a chance to correct himself but Ford declined to do so, reiterating his earlier statement. One of my former (eastern European-American) bosses said, "That's when Ford lost my vote."

Ford lost Ohio by about 5,000 popular votes. Move Ohio and one other state from the Carter column to the Ford column, and Ford would have won the election (at least in the electoral college).

Have many other "famous" (world-renowned) politicians lost a close election after failing to correct a critical error in a speech when given the chance to do so?

Comment: What is the evidence that this was the reason for Ford's defeat? What did he mean when insisting on this statement? How it was understood?

Comment: @Anixx: I was careful to say that Ford lost the election "after" his (mis)-speech. I was careful NOT to say that Ford lost the election "becasue of" it.

Comment: It's not clear that this was a close race before the debate, or that this remark hurt Ford. In September 1976, before Ford made his statement, Carter led Ford by ten points. After the October 6 debate the lead was reduced. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_polling_for_U.S._Presidential_elections#United_States_presidential_election.2C_1976

Comment: @DJClayworth: I just stated the facts. Ford "made a speech." and "Ford lost a close race." I did NOT allege or ask about "cause and effect" EITHER way.

Comment: No, but when you both both 'facts' into one sentence, intentional or not, a connection is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that incidents like these are fairly uncommon.  But tend to happen regularly anyway.  In the last nationwide election poorly thought out statements are attributed with costing several candidates the election.

Mitt Romney's infamous 47% statement is widely considered by conservative pundits as the quote that killed his campaign.

> “ All right, there are 47 percent who are with him, who are dependent
>   upon government, who believe that they are victims, who believe that
>   government has a responsibility to care for them, who believe that
>   they are entitled to healthcare, to food, to housing, you name it.
>   That that’s an entitlement. And the government should give it to them.
>   And they will vote for this president no matter what.” [source](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/lee-morrow/how-the-gop-lost-me_b_3055769.html)

Senator Claire McCaskill was reelected despite being caught "misstating congressional expenses" After her opponent stated that "Legitimate Rape" did not result in pregnancy.

> Missouri Sen. Claire McCaskill (D) successfully defended her seat on
>   Tuesday against opponent Rep. Todd Akin (R), the Tea Party-backed
>   Republican who has become infamous for his comments about "legitimate
>   rape." [Source](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/11/06/todd-akin-election-results-2012_n_2049695.html)

In 2010 after opening up a huge lead in a Senate Race [Chistine O'Donnell's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_O%27Donnell) statement of *"I am not a witch"* is credited with turning the tide against her as voters started to consider if she was a serious candidate.

Both Romney and Akin stuck to their statement for several days until it became apparent even to them that the statements were going to damage their campaigns.  But by the time they tried to reverse course the damage was done.  Akin fell from a significant lead to be blown out in the election by nearly 10 points.

Comment: +1 for giving "examples," but more to the point, which of these politicians was GIVEN A CHANCE TO CORRECT a mis-statement, and failed to take that chance?

Comment: @TomAu - With the exception of Christine ODonnell who's attempt to walk back a statement she made in her teens was the cause of most her problems in the first place.  Both Romney and Akin stuck to their statement until it became apparent it was an anchor around their neck, but by then the damage was done.

Comment: Fair enough. That's the "best" answer of the bunch.

Comment: @TomAu - it's a good answer (+1) but by SE's standards, if 1 answer is a "bunch", this site is in BIG trouble!